# .elf and .hex equivalency? (code, eeprom, fuses, and lock bits all in one)

Tags: programming, avr

I have all configurations (eeprom data, fuses, lockbits) of my ATMega168A together with the code in my C files. The compilation creates an elf file that I use as an all-in-one programming file for production.

Just as a tryout, I converted the elf file to hex with avr-objcopy and saw that the code and configurations are still there (why wouldn't they).

My question is, if the two files are equivalent in case of using them for all-in-one programming. Is there any critical data stripping taking place between elf-to-hex conversion that could affect the actual programming?

Also, I tried again to convert the hex file to bin and saw again the same thing but of course with zero-padding. Except for the obvious different of file size, is there any practical difference when using the bin file and the hex file? Does this padding create any problems? (For example trying to write 0 to addresses that do not exist).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, if the two files are equivalent in case of using them for all-in-one programming. Is there any critical data stripping taking place between elf-to-hex conversion that could affect the actual programming?

Nothing critical, but data stripping does take place. Everything that is in the HEX file is in the ELF file. That is - all the compiled machine code and data.

Basically everything that gets written to the chip is in the HEX file, and the HEX file can be created from what is in the ELF file - ergo the ELF file contains everything that is in the HEX file.

However, not everything that is in the ELF file goes into the HEX file.

The ELF file contains a huge amount more information. Mostly that information is geared towards debugging. There are things like the names and locations of all the *symbols* in the code - that is, the functions and variables, etc. There are breakdowns of all the assembly instructions grouped by source code file and line number.

None of that is relevant for the Arduino environment, but when you're using professional tools to do your development you can use them for realtime debugging and tracing of your program while it's running on the real hardware.

None of that is relevant to putting your program on the chip. It's all used by the PC.

Comment: Majenko your answers are majestic! Thanks!